# Can't Unwrap Value When using this Line of Code Specifically

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I've had this bug where i use avfoundation to make a path to my audio file so when i use this line of code

```
audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Alone", ofType: "m4r")!))
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

It crashes and gives me

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I have all the code right as the compiler dosen't show any errors.
I am using Xcode 9 and swift 4

Comment: It doesn't getting URL path with "Alone.m4r" resource. So, it get crash.

Comment: if you try, you should catch as well or let it crash

Comment: Issue might be due to the forced unwrap that you are using in:        Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Alone", ofType: "m4r")!

Comment: Did you add the file in your bundle? It is crashing because it cannot find the resource in your bundle as others have already suggested.

Comment: i meant that this was part of the do catch statment

Comment: this is my do catch statment:`do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Alone", ofType: "m4r")!))
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }`

Comment: omg thanks so much !

Comment: it wasn't in my bundle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happen because you do forced unwrapping of non-existed path. Generally it's a bad practice. Try to avoid forced unwrapping.
Try this:

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Alone", ofType: "m4r") else {
    print("wrong path")
    return
}
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

Then if you see a "wrong path" in debug console that means the resource with filename "Alone" and extension "m4r" doesn't exist in your app bundle.
Hope this help.